# Hide Javascript Template in Rendered HTML in Django

Tags: jquery, html, django

**NOTE:
This does not have a solution yet. Please help if it is in your expertise area.**

There is an interesting project which integrated the `JQuery-file-upload`
 with Django. Here is the demo page
https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

I use **HTML** inspect element in chrome web browser. From the **HTML** source code seen as a client, it contains the whole javascript template source code. I think it is better not to let user to be able to see this javascript template source code (listed below) just by inspecting the code of rendered **HTML** from the Client side.

How shall it be done to hide this piece of source code from client?
By hiding, it means that we normally only see this kind of content `"<script src="/static/js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>`" without the whole source code. I donot know a way to directly dump the javascript template code into a `filename.js` and then include this into my Django **HTML** template. Please kindly give specific example to hide code like below from client.

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}

    <tr class="template-upload fade">


        <td>
            <span class="preview"></span>
        </td>



        <td>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            <strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
        </td>



        <td>
            <p class="size">Processing...</p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar"
                    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
            </div>
        </td>



        <td>

            {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}



            {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}

        </td>


    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

My Django template engine is as follows:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

Here is what I tried but HTML source code still rendered:

```
script #template-upload {
    display: none;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is the type x-tmpl defined in the projects' templatetags/upload_tags.py
And this section of code is NOT rendered in the HTML before any image is uploaded!

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def upload_js():
    return """
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</p>
            {% if (!o.files.error) { %}
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (!o.files.error && !i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary start">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
            {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>"""
```

**UPDATE AGAIN:**

By changing the type to 'text/javascript', there will be Syntax error in HTML page.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %
```

The cause is that there is '%}' used in the django template upload_tags.py

```
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you really want. Can you explain better.?

Comment: What template  engine you are using ?@coder

Comment: Sure. I updated the question. Basically, this piece of code shall not be visible to normal web user at client side, right?

Comment: I am using this in Django template and update the info above

Comment: What you mean with hide from user?

Comment: It means, normal user cannot directly see the javascript template source code just by inspecting the HTML code using Firefox Firebug or other tools. Normally, we only see this kind of content "<script src="/static/js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>" without the whole source code. But I do not know how to wrap the javascript template code like this?

Comment: Got it!!! I will show you how.

Comment: Much appreciated!!! You are so kind. Waiting for this. I updated the whole question

Comment: have you tried all the options ?

Comment: Are you printing string in the html ? Or is displaying the html tag ?

Comment: Yes. I tried all the options. The html load the tag {% load upload_js %}, then all the javascript content is shown in HTML source code. It displaying the script HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is **wrong**.

```
script #template-upload {
    display: none;
}
```

Please try:

```
script#template-upload {
    display: none;
}
```

With no space. Or just:

```
#template-upload {
    display: none;
}
```

EDIT : try this type.  `type="text/javascript"`

Most of browser has the following css property:

```
script {
    display: none;
}
```

Try this css.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp

Btw you need to  use the following **type** in `script tag` to  fulfill your expected result like:

```
text/javascript (this is default)
text/ecmascript
application/ecmascript
application/javascript
```

Check the complete list here:

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

**EDIT**: PLEASE SEE IF YOU ARE USING THE CORRECT SCRIPT TYPE.

I look for `type="text/x-tmpl"` and didn't find.

Please try. http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/html

```
      <script id="template-upload" type="text/html">
```

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#text

Comment: I tried it. The HTML page still displays the javascript template content.

Comment: Please try changing the type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92451/discussion-between-alvaro-joao-and-coder).